# Is there such a thing as a characteristic polynomial of a certain element in a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I saw a question of this kind- there was given a 3x3 matrix:

$C = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & a \\
2 & 1 & a \\
0 & 2 & a \end{array} \right)$

And the question was: write the characteristic polynomial of $a$.
Is this even a valid question? From what I read on wikipedia, a characteristic polynomial is defined for matrices, not for certain elements in matrices

Comment: I'm pretty sure it says, or at least means "Find $p(a)$, where $p(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $C$" [i.e., "Evaluate the characteristic polynomial of $C$ at the point $a$"]. Could you quote the question verbatim, and tell us where you saw it?

Comment: The matrix and the line that comes after that are exact quotes

Comment: Hm, okay. And the source? As written, it is not a valid question.

Comment: By the way, $p(a)$ is easy to find by directly substituting $x = a$ in $\det(xI - C)$ and expanding the determinant along the last row (being careful with the signs).

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the characteristic polynomial for matrix not for variable. It is determinant of this matrix:

$$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1-\lambda & 0 & a \\
2 & 1-\lambda & a \\
0 & 2 & a-\lambda \end{array} \right) $$